# Validation in Edit component not working in Angular 8

Tags: angular

The validation is getting failed in the edit component module.

```
 import { Component, OnInit, NgZone } from '@angular/core';
 import { BugService } from '../../shared/bug.service';
 import { FormBuilder, Validators, FormGroup, NgForm } from '@angular/forms';
 import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

 @Component({
  selector: 'app-edit-issue',
  templateUrl: './edit-issue.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./edit-issue.component.css']
 })

export class EditIssueComponent implements OnInit {
  IssuesList: any = [];
  updateIssueForm: FormGroup;
  submitted = false;
  ngOnInit() {
  this.updateForm()
  }

constructor(
  private actRoute: ActivatedRoute,
  public bugService: BugService,
  public fb: FormBuilder,
  private ngZone: NgZone,
  private router: Router,
) {
  var id = this.actRoute.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
  this.bugService.GetIssue(id).subscribe((data) => {
    this.updateIssueForm = this.fb.group({
      issue_name: [data.issue_name],
      issue_message: [data.issue_message],
      issue_number: [data.issue_number]
    })
  })
}

updateForm() {
  this.updateIssueForm = this.fb.group({
    issue_name: ['', Validators.required],
    issue_message: [''],
    issue_number: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(20)]]


  })
}
get s() {
  console.info(this.updateIssueForm.controls);
  return this.updateIssueForm.controls;
}

submitForm() {
  console.info(this.updateIssueForm.invalid);
  this.submitted = true;
  if (this.updateIssueForm.invalid) {
    return;
  } else {
    var id = this.actRoute.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
    this.bugService.UpdateBug(id, this.updateIssueForm.value).subscribe(res => {
      this.ngZone.run(() => this.router.navigateByUrl('/issues-list'))
    })
  }
}
}
```

edit-issue-component.html

```
<div class="container wrapper wrapper2">
<div class="row">

    <!-- Form -->
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <h3>Add Issue</h3>
        <form [formGroup]="updateIssueForm" (ngSubmit)="submitForm()">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Issue</label>
                <input type="text" formControlName="issue_name" class="form-control"
                    [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && s.issue_name.errors }">
                <div *ngIf="submitted && s.issue_name.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
                    <div *ngIf="s.issue_name.errors.required">Password is required</div>

                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Issue Number</label>
                <input type="text" formControlName="issue_number" class="form-control"
                    [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && s.issue_number.errors }">
                <div *ngIf="submitted && s.issue_number.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
                    <div *ngIf="s.issue_number.errors.required">Password is required</div>
                    <div *ngIf="s.issue_number.errors.minlength">Password must be at least 6 characters</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Issue Details</label>
                <textarea class="form-control" formControlName="issue_message" rows="3" maxlength="50"></textarea>
            </div>
            <div class="text-center">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mr-4">Update</button>

            </div>
        </form>
    </div>


</div>
```

Here if it try to validate the issue_number the validation fails. i.e If I try to submit the form with empty issue_number, then the error message should be show, but the form object is getting submitted successfully

As I am new to Angular 8 can anyone help me to fix this issue.

Comment: @Maihan Nijat  I am getting false in console

Comment: What do you mean by "the validation fails". Be precise. What are you doing? (example: I am entering hello in the issue number field). What do you expect to happen? (example: I expect the message "hahahaha" to be displayed under that field). What happens instead? (example: the message "hihihihi" appears instead).

Comment: @JB Nizet If I try to submit the form with empty issue_number, then the error message should be show, but the form object is getting submitted successfully

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works as expected, partly since of the asynchronous nature of `this.bugService.GetIssue(id)`. So you are calling `updateForm()` from `ngOnInit()`, but you are also creating a form in `GetIssue()`. So the `OnInit` function is called before the one in `GetIssue()`. Inside `GetIssue()` you are actually creating a new formgroup, so I assume that you might think that the Validators get transferred there, well, they don't. You would probably want to use `patchValue` or `setValue` inside `GetIssue()`, which will just update the original form and not create a new one (without validators). Also keep constructor as clean as possible, we have the `OnInit` to call such things like http-requests.

All in all, I suggest the following, to remove code from constructor and do:

```ts
ngOnInit() {
  this.updateForm();
  const id = this.actRoute.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
  this.bugService.GetIssue(id).subscribe((data) => {
    this.updateIssueForm.patchValue(data);
  })
}
```

Or just build the form after getting values from the `GetIssue()` and add a `*ngIf="updateIssueForm"` in template. Depending on how you want to handle this.

**EDIT:** As you asked to see the other option I mentioned above. Then that would mean that you don't call `updateForm()` at all in `OnInit`, but just build the form inside `GetIssue()`:

```ts
this.bugService.GetIssue(id).subscribe((data) => {
  this.updateIssueForm = this.fb.group({
    issue_name: [data.issue_name, Validators.required],
    issue_message: [data.issue_message],
    issue_number: [data.issue_number, [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(20)]]
  })
})
```

That would though mean that you would need a `*ngIf="updateIssueForm"` in template, for example on the form tag itself. Why? Because, as earlier mentioned `GetIssue()` is asynchronous, and template is rendered before form has been built, and would therefore throw an error about form being `undefined`;

Comment: Thanks for the help. Can you please elaborate on the second work around you have posted. It will be helpful for me to understand the Angular in better way.

Comment: updated answer, very similar to what you were doing originally, except not call `updateForm` at all and setting the validators also inside `GetIssue`